# Get a certain child property from parent instead of the whole object in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

In an http get method, I want to get the users' ids associated with the todoItem without getting the full user object (just its id). This is what I have so far:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<TodoItem>>> GetTodoItems()
{
        var todoItem = await _context.TodoItems.Include(x => x.User).ToListAsync();

        if (!todoItem.Any()) 
           return NotFound();

        return todoItem;
}
```

Current output:

```
{
    "id": "47167fe1-4831-4612-8f50-4ba4c70e7eac",
    "name": "read book",
    "isComplete": false,
    "secrete": "no secrete",
    "user": {
        "id": "3ca7b4b8-dd63-40ce-9d3a-3fc88286da64",
        "email": "Lynne87@test.com",
        "firstName": "Lynne",
        "lastName": "Harber"
    }
}
```

Required output:

```
{
    "id": "47167fe1-4831-4612-8f50-4ba4c70e7eac",
    "name": "read book",
    "isComplete": false,
    "secrete": "no secrete",
    "user": "3ca7b4b8-dd63-40ce-9d3a-3fc88286da64",
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `Select` with just the members you want before calling `ToListAsync`. If you expect only a single result use `FirstOrDefaultAsync` or `SingleOrDefaultAsync`. You don't need `Include` if `Select` returns all the necessary fields

Comment: BTW the desired output is no longer a `ToDoItem`, which means the return type should change and reflect the actual output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Select` with just the members you want before calling ToListAsync. You don't need `Include` if `Select` returns all the necessary fields. The desired output is no longer a ToDoItem, which means the return type should change and reflect the actual output. Either create a new DTO type that matches the output or return just an ActionResult:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetTodoItems()
{
    var items = await _context.TodoItems
                              .Select(x=>  new {
                                     x.Id,
                                     x.Name,
                                     x.IsComplete,
                                     x.Secrete,
                                     User = x.User.Id     
                              })
                              .ToListAsync();
            
    if (todoItem..Length==0) 
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(items);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I'm new to entity framework so there are lots of things I still don't understand. Thanks